# How to read XML Attributes in Haxe?

Tags: haxe, openfl

How can I read a XML attribute from a XML file in Haxe?
This is my XML file:

```
<scene>
    <page image="0.png" text="Hello"/>
    <page image="1.png" text="Goodbye"/>
</scene>
```

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Access](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/xml/Access.html) API to access to the most common Xml methods.